# How to highlight if there is a cell in that same row already highlighted in Excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have this table.

[image]

I want to do two things:

1. Highlight all values in 'File ID' in which its corresponding 'Report Date' has a highlighted cell.
2. Pull out a column which lists only the rows in which 'File ID' has a highlighted cell in 'Report Date'.

How can I approach this? Any tips much appreciated! :)

Comment: What is the logic that for coloring the report date cells yellow? If there is a logic you should reuse this to do what you want. Formatting based on colors is no good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Is the highlighting conditional formatting ? If yes, you can use the same formula as in the formatting to check if the cell fills the condition.

If not, you need vba to get the formatting of a cell. This article has can help you with that : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/colors.aspx

Then for your filtered column, if you want it to only contain the relevant rows you can use the filter function. Again, you'll need vba if the highlighting is not done with conditional formatting.

My recomandation would be to stop highlighting by hand if that's what you've been doing : tte simplest solution is to add a column where you indicate if the cells should be highlighted, then base your conditional formatting and formulas on that column.

Answer (score 0):

1)copy column 2 paste special in column 1 -formats
change column 1 format to genral

2)i asume you want a third column of only yellow field id so just copy column 1 value sort by colour delet remaining you get your column of onlyyellow number

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).